Product of uniformizable spaces
I say that a space $X$ is uniformizable if there exists a familily of pseudometrics  $ \{d_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A} $  such that induces its topology.
I want to prove the following thm:
If $\{X_{\mu}\}_{\mu \in L}$ is a familily of uniformizable spaces with family of pseudometrics $\{D_{\mu}\}_{\mu \in L}$ where $D_{\mu} = \{d_{\mu_{\alpha}}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ then $X = \prod_{\mu \in L}{X_{\mu}}$ is uniformizable
My attemp:
I want to prove that the product topology $\tau$ is the same as the topology $\tau_{D}$ induced by the family of pseudometrics $D = \{d_{\mu_{\alpha}}' \colon \alpha \in A, \mu \in L \}$ where $d'_{\mu_{\alpha}}(x,y) = d_{\mu_{\alpha}}(\pi_{\mu}(x),\pi_{\mu}(y))$ with $\pi_{\mu}$ the projection of $X$ onto $X_{\mu}$.
But I dont know how to prove that any open in $\tau$ is open in $\tau_{D}$.
Can someone help me?

Consider an open set in the usual basis of the product topology $\tau$, that is, a set of the form
$$
O:=\left(\prod_{\mu\in L\setminus F}X_\mu\right)\times\prod_{\mu\in F}O_\mu,
$$
where $F\subseteq L$ is finite and $O_\mu$ is open in $X_\mu$ for all $\mu\in F$. And let $p=(p_\mu)_{\mu\in L}$ be a point in $O_\mu$.
It will be enough to show that there is a $\tau_D$-open set containing $p$ and contained in $O$.
Indeed, note that for all $\mu\in F$, as the set $O_\mu$ is open and contains $p_\mu$, there must be some pseudometrics $d_{\mu_{1}},\dots,d_{\mu_{n}}$ and some $\varepsilon>0$ such that the set $U_\mu:=\{x\in X_\mu;d_{\mu}(p_\mu,x)<\varepsilon\text{ for all }i=1,\dots,n\}$ is contained in $U_\mu$.
Note that for all $\mu\in F$ the set $U_\mu\otimes\prod_{\nu\in L\setminus\{\mu\}}X_\nu$ is open in $\tau_D$. The intersection $\bigcap_{\mu\in F}U_\mu\otimes\prod_{\nu\in L\setminus\{\mu\}}X_\nu$ is open in $\tau_D$, contains $p$ and is contained in $O$, so we are done.
